# could not find framework in eclipse RCP application

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have developed one eclipse RCP application which I am calling from my own Java program.
When I run my own Java program from command prompt (windows) it is perfectly working and giving the results.

But when I have integrated with the ant build script in eclipse 3.2 it is giving the following problem:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.launcher 4 0 Dec 02, 2009 10:53:17.608
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find framework
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.getBootPath(Main.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:704)
    at xxx.xxx.xxxx.MyCodeGenerator.main(MyCodeGenerator.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.run(ExecuteJava.java:202)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:134)
```

Can you please help me what could be the possible reasons for this error.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg18288.html), you:

- do not only have to add the platform plugins you wish to export to the list of dependent plugins of your feature,

[image: Dependencies]

- but you also have to the list of included plugins

[image: Required plugins]

(See [this project](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/compappwiki.nsf/dx/how-to-write-an-eclipse-component-in-40-minutes-or-less) for instance)

Make sure you "Validate Plug-ins" before you launch your RCP (see [this thread](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-uima-user/200905.mbox/%3C4A081067.7070902@ki.informatik.uni-wuerzburg.de%3E)).
With the Launch Configuration Dialog, in the "Plug-ins" Tab, there is a "Validate Plug-ins" button that you can click to verify that all the dependency of the "selected" plug-ins are satisfied.
If there are some errors, you can click the "`Add Required Plug-ins`" to correct the error.