# MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform

Tags: java, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [could not find framework in eclipse RCP application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832556/could-not-find-framework-in-eclipse-rcp-application)

```
!SESSION Wed Sep 15 15:57:56 CAT 2010 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.launcher 4 0 Sep 15, 2010 15:57:56.342
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find framework
 at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.getBootPath(Main.java:395)
 at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:174)
 at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:704)
 at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:688)
```

Comment: google or use the SO search first - just entered the message of the exception at google and the very first hit was the duplicate and answered question on SO...

Comment: Yes, it is an exception.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the configuration of eclipse is broken. Check the other eclipse copy, the property 'osgi.framework' in configuration/config.ini.