# Exception while running my WAR in eclipse using TomCat 7

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7, war, eclipse-rap

I'm trying to launch my rap web app from eclipse using TomCat 7, but it causes the following exception:

> HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet equinoxbridgeservlet threw exception
>
> message Servlet.init() for servlet equinoxbridgeservlet threw exception
>
> **description:**
>
> The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> **exception:**
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet equinoxbridgeservlet threw exception
>       org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>       org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
>       org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
>       org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>
> **root cause:**
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find framework
>       org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.FrameworkLauncher.start(FrameworkLauncher.java:421)
>       org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.BridgeServlet.init(BridgeServlet.java:65)
>       javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
>       org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>       org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
>       org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
>       org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Did any one had this kind of issue ?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832556/could-not-find-framework-in-eclipse-rcp-application).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have osgi bundle included in your WAR/config.ini?

Comment: @ ivan : I figured it out this morning, the issue was the jar that gets included for osgi, org.eclipse.osgi_version-SDK-4.2.1.jar is shown with wrong naming format while deploying with tomcat 6 and 7, it was showing org.eclipse.osgi"-" instead of "_"version-SDK-4.2.1.jar. After I changed it to "_" it got fixed. This happens only in eclipse though. Thanks